# Android, Threads - handlers/asynctask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, handlers

Am a noob learning Android via a book and for threading I see there are 3 main ways that are explained in the book:

- Handlers via messaging
- Handlers via post
- Asynctask

All 3 seem good, my question is:
Is there a specific time when you use one of the above? Or is it personal preference?

EDIT:
If its not personal preference, please give me an example as to when you would use one if not the other (even a link would be appreciated)

Because I am planning on having multiple threads running (eg, one for total app running time, one for time before answer is selected etc in the app, one for moving the background image etc) and want to know which to choose. I can do the functionality of what I want using either of these 3 methods so am confused as to why there are 3 when it can be done with either one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handler is a very basic way that allows you to execute some code on a different thread, typically UI thread. It does not tell you how to run your threads and you are free to do whatever you want in that respect. I would choose `handleMessage` approach if you have explicit messaging. That is you need to have some data sent and received. If you just need to do something, you can use `Runnable`. However, both methods are usable and a choice often would be result of a preference.

`AsyncTask` is higher level concept that uses handlers under the hood. If you use it, you will not have to deal with threads yourself. Your asynchronous code will be executed via thread pool and controlled by the framework. You will have two methods that allow you to execute code on UI thread (`onPostExecute` and `onProgressUpdate`).

In a nutshell, choose `AsyncTask` for most things that you do with multiple threads it will absolve you of a need to deal with thread management yourself. If you must have your own threads only then use handlers. Note however, that there are other cases when you have to use handlers. For example, with `Messenger`. Also I had cases when using `onProgressUpdate` is not sufficient. In this case I would use handler as well from `doInBackground`.

Comment: Thank you, that was a very clear explanation and what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

AsynTasks are probably the best fit for complex tasks, like when you would need a lot of processing and lot of message passing. You could achieve them through Handlers as well, but personally speaking, you code gets a little messy that way.

Answer (score 1):

Handler: Bound to the thread that created it. Queue/Enqueue's tasks in the message queue. When it enqueues a message, it hands it to another thread than the one that created it. Think of it as an agent to the thread. It takes care of requests sent to it and delegates them accordingly.

Post/Messaging: As explained above, it's just the handler posting (queueing) or messaging (enqueueing).

Asynctask: Is a thread that mainly is for small tasks that need to be done in the background and update the UI dependent on their progress (think loading bar, or a download; UI being updated with that progress).

Answer (score 1):

Check out Needle and you can forget Handlers and Asynctasks. Needle is an open-source, simple but powerful multithreading library for Android. With it you can say things like:

```
Needle.onMainThread().execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // e.g. change one of the views
    }
});
```

or

```
Needle.onBackgroundThread().execute(new UiRelatedTask<Integer>() {
    @Override
    protected Integer doWork() {
        int result = 1+2;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void thenDoUiRelatedWork(Integer result) {
        mSomeTextView.setText("result: " + result);
    }
});
```

- very simple API
- fixed thread pool size
- customizable thread pool size
- supports UI interaction ("do work and then use result on UI thread")
- android 1.5+
- behaves the same on all platform versions

Check it out on GitHub: https://github.com/ZsoltSafrany/needle